# Adding 6 months to a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it at all possible too, while creating a table in MySQL, add 6 months to a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? If so how? I am able to do it when inserting data into the table, but I was hoping it would just auto add itself in.
Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS promos
(
expiryDateOfReward DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE_ADD(MONTH, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think MySQL supports expressions on date/time for default values.

More recent versions support generated columns.  This allows you to do:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS promos
(
    createdAt datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    expiryDateOfReward DATETIME generated always as (createdAt + interval 6 month)
);
```

Also note that the syntax for adding six months is suitable for MySQL.

Comment: @GeneSmith . . . You actually prefer a *trigger* to a simple column declaration?

Comment: it's not that I prefer it. I just thought I would give a trigger a try because I already have a few other triggers set up. On a side note, do you think there is an advantage of using the one over the other?

Comment: @GeneSmith . . . Yes.  Triggers generally slow inserts down and are more cumbersome to maintain (having all the logic in the table definition is simpler).

Comment: oh ok, if there is a performance difference then I may as well rather do it your way then

Comment: "Yes. Triggers generally slow inserts down and are more cumbersome to maintain (having all the logic in the table definition is simpler)" Yes but on the other side  generated columns slows down SELECT queries when expiryDateOfReward is used in the select qeuries @GeneSmith so you might want to change that into also using **`STORED`** Then it also possible to index the generated column.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . Materializing the field (as needed for the trigger) uses extra space, so the table occupies more data pages.  The additional I/O may entirely offset (and more) the expense of doing the calculation for the `select`.  My preference for computed columns is based much more on maintainability than performance.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL does not support expressions on date/time for default values. 
But you can use a trigger for this one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER setExpiryDateOfReward
BEFORE INSERT ON promos
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.expiryDateOfReward = NEW.expiryDateOfReward + INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gBHjoNC5jMUeJ89Ya2MujS/0

The generated columns from Gordon Linoff is a more suitable answer but requires a minimal MySQL version of 5.7 
 
The trigger solution requires a minimal MySQL version of 5.1

Comment: I never actually thought of using a trigger. Thanks. I think I'll actually use a trigger rather